# Smallest Linux distribution with multicore support?

Tags: linux, operating-system

Does anyone know about the smallest Linux kernel I can use to play with? I don't need security, desktop, not even vesa, really, but I do need it to support multicore (which is why freertos is off the table per se). Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ArchLinux](http://www.archlinux.org/) comes to mind.

Answer (score 1):

Try DSL: http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/

Comment: +1 from me, but it's still sitting at 50 megs.

Comment: its certainly not the smallest, but its feature to size ratio is great

Comment: Look's like you beat me to it :) (I think of Stack Overflow as a race sometimes, a race to answer the questions first)

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is something non-graphical, you can give a try to Arch Linux, which is a very customizable distro and you can go only with the core system. It's always up to date because it is a rolling-release distro.

You can also go with Debian minimal, but due to the project targets, its repos can be a little old.

For multicore support, I think any Linux 2.6.x is capable of this, even if your kernel don't come with it by default (very old kernels), you always can to rebuild your own with multicore support, only be sure to activate the SMP modules.